# Can a BitmapImage or byte[] be converted to a System.Windows.Media.DrawingImage?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have searched for hours, but can find no answer.

Can a `BitmapImage` or a `byte[]` be converted to a `System.Windows.Media.DrawingImage`?

It seems there are many methods to convert a `DrawingImage` to a `BitmapImage`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Think about it, how would you possibly create a DrawingImage's `Drawing` - which is vector graphics - from the pixel raster of a bitmap? For what purpose do you explicitly need a DrawingImage?

Comment: @Clemens I tend to conceptualize way before I can catch up with the actual implementation --and could see I was headed in this direction. You are absolutely correct, most all information necessary to create a DrawingImage is lost when converting a Drawing image to a bitmap. Thanks for clarification. I missed the concept that a DrawingImage is vector, whereas a bitamp is simply pixel. :)